# Check thread status while leaving it in a waitable state

Tags: c, multithreading, status, wait

I am wondering if it is possible to check the status of a thread, which could possibly be in a waitable state but doesn't have to be and if it is in a waitable state I would like to leave it in that state.

Basically, how can I check the status of a thread without changing its (waitable) state.

By waitable, I mean if I called wait(pid) it would return properly and not hang.

Let me also add that I am tracing a multithreaded program, therefore I cannot change the code of it. Also, I omitted this information as well but this is a Linux-based system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about processes or threads? The `wait` function acts on processes, not threads, so your question as-written is not valid.

For (child) processes, you can check the state by calling `waitid` with the `WNOWAIT` flag. This will leave the process in a waitable state.

For threads, on some implementatiosn you can call `pthread_kill(thread, 0)` and check for `ESRCH` to determine if the thread has exited or not, while leaving `thread` in a joinable state. Note that this is valid **only if the thread is joinable**. If it was detached or already joined, you are invoking Undefined Behavior and your program should crash or worse. Unfortunately, there is no requirement that `pthread_kill` report `ESRCH` in this case, so it might falsely report that a thread still exists when in fact it already terminated. Of course, formally there is **no difference** between a thread that's sitting around forever between the call to `pthread_exit` and actual termination, and a thread that has actually finished terminating, so the question is a bit meaningless. In other words, there's no requirement that a joinable thread ever terminate until `pthread_join` is blocked waiting for it to terminate.

Comment: I am already using waitpid now to wait on threads, so I am going to have to disagree. You should take a look at the waitpid man page at the section under Linux Notes. linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid 
Either way though, I am not just trying to figure out if it is either running or terminated, I also want to know whether it is stopped and if so by what signal

Comment: OK then you're just writing horribly broken, non-portable code. Also a thread cannot terminate or stop due to a signal. Only processes can terminate or stop due to signals. For a thread you should be using pthread synchronization primitives to determine it's state. One simple approach would be to have the thread post a semaphore when it terminates. Then you could use `sem_trywait` to query whether the thread has terminated.

Comment: If you read my question again, you will see that I said I am tracing the multithreaded process therefore I cannot change what the code does I am just tracing it and trying to determine it's state at a specific point in time. Second, this code is for a specific architecture only so I have no concern if it is portable. Finally, a thread is just a special type of process in linux so again I disagree with what you are saying about not being able to stop a thread with a signal because I already do that currently.

Comment: The signal will be delivered to the whole process and stop the whole process. You should be using `ptrace` to trace...

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I know how to trace a process however I would like to retrieve the status of a thread as described in my question. Do you know a way to do that? If all you have is advice on what you think I am doing wrong in my program please don't bother to reply.

Comment: I think adding the `WNOWAIT` flag, as I said in my answer, should work. There's probably another way using `ptrace` too though.

Comment: I see, I apologize for missing that part. I have tried that before and didn't have much luck, for now I am just using the ptrace request PTRACE_GETSIGINFO which works well at discovering what signal has stopped a process if it is stopped which is the most important information for me at the moment. Thank you for taking your time to help.

Answer (score 0):

Do  you want to do something like this (pseudo-code)?

```
if (status(my_thread) == waiting)
    do_something();
else
    do_something_else();
```

If that is indeed what you are trying to do, you are exposing yourself to race conditions. For example, what if `my_thread` wakes up after `status(my_thread)` but before `do_something()` (or even before `== waiting`)?

You might want to consider condition variables for safely communicating "status" between threads. Thread-safe queue might also be an option...

BTW, Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory has an excellent tutorial on multithreading concepts at https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ (including condition variables). This particular document uses POSIX API, but concepts that are explained are universal.

Comment: I am tracing the multithreaded program, therefore I don't think I could apply these concepts given that I cannot change the code.