# get thread status, like top

Tags: c, multithreading

What is the linux API to query the status of a thread, like the `top -H` command can do? I do not need portability, it just has to work on modern x86[_64] linux.

*I do not want to only know if the thread is alive or terminated*. I need to know if it's sleeping also.

Comment: Did you try to search StackOverflow for similar questions first? What about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880301/check-thread-status-while-leaving-it-in-a-waitable-state)?

Comment: @EitanT yes, and that question doesn't address my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `top` reads its information from `/proc`, on Linux at least.

**Update**: For `top`'s sources you might like to read here: [Procps - The /proc file system utilities](http://procps.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: could you give a bit more info? I've always found the /proc hierarchy to be pretty much a mess and not very well documented.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use libproc, from procps ( http://procps.sourceforge.net/).

There isn't any API documentation online, but http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2011/02/listing-processes-with-libproc.html is a pretty good introduction to using libproc.